# Include values to the barplot and pie charts in R

Tags: r, statistics, bar-chart, pie-chart

I have data in this form:

[image]

```
proprete.freq <- table(cnData$proprete)
proprete.freq.genre <-table(cnData$genre,cnData$proprete)
```

[image]

I am using these functions (barplot and pie) to plot the data:

```
barplot(proprete.freq.genre, col = heat.colors(length(rownames(proprete.freq.genre)))
    , main="Proprete", beside = TRUE)

pie(proprete.freq, col=rainbow(3), names.arg=avis, main="Propreté")
```

Here is the result:

[image]

[image]

**Question**: How to include the value just on top of the barplots and below the categorical variables for the pie.
Something like that:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a general approach:

1. `pie` has a labels parameter so you can just use that, use `\n` for a line break, and add text under the name
2. `barplot` has a return value which are the x-coordinates of each bar, so just use `text` along with the data (for the y-coordinates), and use `pos = 3` to put the label above that `{x, y}` point.

ex:

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
pie(1:3, labels = sprintf('%s\n%s%%', 1:3, round(1:3 / 6 * 100)))
bp <- barplot(VADeaths, beside = TRUE)
text(c(bp), c(VADeaths), labels = c(VADeaths), pos = 3, xpd = NA)
```

[image]