# Plot pie chart and histogram using R from table with frequency count

Tags: r, plot, histogram, pie-chart, frequency

I have a distribution frequency as an output from a java program as a csv file, with the following format:

```
push 210
mov 270
jmp 150
cp 190
..so on
```

I'm fairly new to R, I want to input it into a table and project it as a pie chart and/or a histogram to have a visual representation with labels and % possibly, similar to the following image..

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHNss.png]

I know from searches and reading that it'll be something along the line,

```
myfile <- read.csv("sample.csv", sep="/t");
myfreq <- table(myfile);
pie(myfreq);
hist(myfreq);
```

I know `table(myfile)` gives a frequency distribution, but it counts the frequency instead of using it as is.

Comment: Are you saying you want to use the data 'as is' that is imported from the `.csv` file? If so you can just use the `myfile` variable as it should already be stored as a 'table' after the `read.csv()` function.

Comment: consider using a barplot instead `barplot(myfile[, 2], names = myfile[, 1]); pie(myfile[, 2], labels = myfile[, 1])` also [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909843/include-values-to-the-barplot-and-pie-charts-in-r) may be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Going by your example input file, when loading, you need to specify `header=F` as there's no header.
- When loading, you need `sep='\t'` to use a tab separator.
- `table()` does count frequencies, but since your input data already has frequencies, there's no need to call it here.
- You can label the slices with percentages, but you have to calculate them yourself and pass the values for the `labels` argument to `pie()`.

---

```
dat <- read.csv('sample.csv', sep='\t', header=F, col.names=c('inst','freq') );
dat;
##   inst freq
## 1 push  210
## 2  mov  270
## 3  jmp  150
## 4   cp  190
cols <- rainbow(nrow(dat));
pie(dat$freq,labels=paste0(round(dat$freq/sum(dat$freq)*100,2),'%'),col=cols);
legend('bottom',legend=dat$inst,pch='■',ncol=nrow(dat),bty='n',col=cols);
```

---

[image: pie]

Comment: Thanks, it worked out great except for one thing. I'm not sure how you used pch block. But I'm sure a quick search will fix that. Thank you.

Comment: @Ankit, I actually just grabbed a Unicode character, U+25A0, it was kind of random. Basically just looked through http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/unicode/unidata25.html until I found one that I judged to be the best match for your screenshot.